# Calculating how much data can the computer transfer - Computer Architecture

Tags: architecture, transfer

Consider a 32-bit microprocessor, with a 16-bit external data bus, driven by an 300 -MHz
input clock. How many seconds you need to transfer 256 MB data? How many seconds
you need to transfer 20 GB data if the bus is available only 35% of the time?

- I know it is either (4B x 300MHz)/256MB or (2B x 300MHz)/256MB but not sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 2B because 2 bytes is 16 bits.

The combination of 16 bit external data bus and a 300MHz clock sounds fictional to me. I think that by the time busses ran on 300MHz clocks transfer rates already are measured in GB/s and multiple transfers per clock tick happened.

When 16 bit busses were used the transfer rate was 16MB/s on a 8MHz clock: https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/meesh/cmsc411/website/projects/buses/buses.html

Comment: Hi @Gerballi, thank you for the response. Does that mean that the speed of the microprocessor is not important and we only have to calculate using data bus size & clock?

Comment: Yes. You're calculating the bus bandwith, not actual transfers rates. In reality the transfer rate of data only approaches the bus bandwith for very short periods at best. For a CPU you can't do a calculation like this; calculations per second or max data throughput can't be calculated based on clock speeds. They're related, but not in a linear or straightforward way.

Comment: Hi @MeliFetaji, Could you mark my answer as correct? It would mean a lot. Thanks.